is it possible use the find function in google sheets for multiple items?
I'm looking to find over 100 items in my sheet, they all have different ID's attached to them, I could manually do this but to save time I thought group find + copy function would help. I'm super new to sheets so I'd appreciate any sort of help. Thanks
I tried used ctrl + f for a regular find though it appears it's limited in searching for multiple ID's

Please include an example of what you would like to achieve, it is hard to understand what is your goal.

try:
=FILTER(A:B; REGEXMATCH(A:A; "item1|item2"))

where A:B will be your range
and A:A will be column to search in your items
then "item1|item2" can be expanded manually like "item1|item2|item3"
or if those items are in some range it can be TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; C:C)
or if it is comma separated use SUBSTITUTE(C1; ","; "|")
then if you want to avoid false flags like item1<>item10 you can do "^item1$|^item2$"
or with dynamic join it would be "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^"; 1; C:C)&"$"
depends what you need and whats your data. have fun.
